# Trie Printing in C

Tags: c, trie

I'm having trouble printing out the words of a `trie` in C. I've implemented the `trie` like this:

```
struct trie {

struct trie *children[26];
char letter;
int wordEnd;

};


void printSubtree(struct trie *subtree) {
    int i;  
    if (subtree == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i<26;i++) {
            if (subtree->children[i]!= NULL) {
                printf("%c", subtree->children[i]->letter);
                printSubtree( subtree->children[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printResult(){
    struct trie *temp; 
    temp = master;
    int i ;
    if (temp){
        for (i = 0; i<26;i++) {
            if (temp->children[i]!= NULL) {
                printf("%c", temp->children[i]->letter);
                printSubtree(temp->children[i]);
                printf("\n");
                printf("\n");
            } 
        } 
    }   
}
```

I know this is not right, but I'm not sure how to use recursion to print out words. If the `trie` has `"abc"` and `"abe"` stored as distinct words, what ends up printing out is only the string `"abce"`, insert of both `"abc"` and `"abe"` as different words. 
Subsequently, I'm unsure how to use DFS to print it out, because wouldn't DFS travel all the way to `"abc"`, print that out, then go back to the level of `"b"`, see that `"b"` has a children that has not been visited,  then print it out, resulting in the string `"abce"` anyway?

Comment: You probably need to keep the whole string that represents the word so far and to which you append letters as you descend the trie. When you find a word, print that string. You can't just print letters as you go, because they will only be printed once, but might belong to several words.

Answer (score 3):

A suitable way to print the contents of the trie would be to use a user-defined stack which stores the characters in the path from the root to the current node. On each recursive call, the character contained in the visited note is pushed; on leaving a node, the top of the stack would be popped. Each time a leaf of the trie is reached recursively, the entire stack would be printed. If depth-first search is used without the user-defined stack, the path from the root to the current node is represented only implicitly in the call stack, which cannot be accessed directly.